# This kernel requires an x84-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU

Tags: kernel, cpu

I have used Ubuntu on my laptop for several years without problems.
I now want to download it to my desktop. I followed all the steps, but when it starts to load I get "This kernel requires an x84-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU." I have read all previous questions on this matter but nothing seems to help. I have tried using the 32 bit programme but it does the same. I use AMI bios v02.61 and I cannot see a virtualisation setting but I have been told that this is already enabled.
I am running short of idea's and any help I can get will be appreciated.
I loaded the 64 bit system but in reading another persons problem, he was advised to try the 32 bit and it worked.
The version I downloaded is Ubuntu 14.04.3 desktop-i386 iso
The desktop is an Intel (R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2,8 GHz 2GBz Ram.

Comment: What do you mean be "tried using the 32 bit programme" ?  Perhaps pointing to the links of the ISO's  you've tried will help here.

Comment: What is your CPU and OS (assuming you're using virtual machine)?

Comment: Thank you fossfreedom. What download do you recommend to enable me to load ubuntu on to my desktop please?

Comment: Ok, maybe I am confused and have misled you. I have a CPU currently running XP. As I have been very happy with Ubuntu on my laptop, I want to load 14.04 and replace the XP program on the desktop.

Comment: I need you to say which ISO you have tried - e.g. any of these? http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/  hint - the 32bit ISO's are "i386" - 64bit ISO's are "amd64"

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;)** We are goid, but not magicians nor telepaths. *you* need to tell *us* which versions you've already tried please provide: 1. The brand and model number of your desktop 2. The links to the Ubuntu versions you've already tried. Please do this by [edit]ing your question and clarify everything a bit. **:)**

Answer (score 0):

There are two main arch types: x86_64 (64 bit) and x86 (32 bit).
Well it appears that you're trying to install a 64bit version of Ubuntu on a computer with a non 64-bit capable CPU. Pretty sure the i386/32bit installers don't contain 64bit kernels so you must've dwnloaded the wrong version.

Comment: Thank you all. I am starting from scratch again following everyone's advice. I will get back soon and let you know if I come right.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. The USB flash I was using showed up in the bios. I selected bios to boot from it. It seemed to boot and gave me all the start-up options. It would then freeze until I selected "Help" I would then get the message "This kernel requires an x84-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU." I realised that the flash was not booting and burned a disk. This worked like a dream. So in short although the flash was seen in the bios it was not booting.
Thank all of you for your help.